# Module access in Sugar CRM - difference (non-admin) between soap and web?

Tags: sugarcrm

We've a custom rigging of Sugar (using GWT for various front end stuff), and we use the SOAP API for much of our querying (vs. directly to the DB).

One of the API calls to check credentials is get_available_modules, which returns all available modules for a given user.  How could a user have access to a module in the web interface, but not via a SOAP call (same session id?).

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure on your question. Do you want a user to hve access to one set of modules from web and another set via soap? Or is there a difference on you setup?

First off, there should **not** be a difference between a user's available modules on web and soap calls.

If you want a different set for each access method, you need to change e.g. "get_available_modules" in the soap web service. One crude approch could be to make an override array in config_override.php abd check against that array in the soap function.